# Do we have a homework policy?

Tags: discussion

I was going through some other SE sites and I came upon [Economics' homework policy](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions) which lead me to wonder if we have any such policy here on Aviation. Do we have/need a homework policy or is it not necessary for this site?

Comment: If "homework" means exam or test questions then we've already discussed it [here](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/394/62), although inconclusively. You might want to add your thoughts to that question?

Answer (score 4):

The general consensus [on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework) is that we don't give out answers, though we may give helpful tips, guidance and advice (kind of like a good teacher would also do, given the time).

I don't see Aviation.SE as being significantly different from other SE sites, so I think following Meta's guidance on this is a good idea.

Comment: Note that the one you linked, is a duplicate to a post that welcomes H/W questions.