# Do "please check my homework & tell me what I did wrong" questions add value to the site?

Tags: discussion

Looking at [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/calculating-cl-and-cd-from-cp-vs-x-c-graph-data), although there are many similar examples out there. I don't see that questions like this add value here, as they tend to be uninteresting for anybody who doesn't have the same assignment or isn't making the same mistake. These questions often ***are*** answerable by some of the engineers here, which helps the OP but then in turn encourages more questions of the same flavor.

Is there a consensus about the acceptability (or lack thereof) of such questions here?

Comment: Happy to discuss this again, so not closing as a duplicate, but we have discussed this already: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/do-we-have-a-homework-policy and https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394/should-we-answer-exam-or-test-questions

Comment: As you can see from the questions linked above, and the answer below, the general consensus is that the right sort of homework questions are fine. In that vein, please avoid borderline unfriendly comments such as "This is not a do your homework site!". If you don't want to answer them that is fine, just move on.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see much of a problem with this kind of questions, apart from that I prefer to see formulas in mathjax rather than photocopy.

The author shows that he has quite a good level of understanding of the topic and tried to solve that problem by himself.

This kind of questions give an opening to explain fundamental theory, and perhaps mix in some practical advice ([like this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45906/19) from Peter Kämpf). That is valuable to more people than just the OP.

What is not acceptable to me is when people have the audacity to post a photo of their homework question and ask us to write the answer, without showing any effort themselves.

Comment: Re: *What is not acceptable to me is when people have the audacity (...)* -- what is the suggestion, close the topic?

Comment: @ymb1 what do you mean? Close the question in such case? Yes

Answer (score 0):

I find that such questions rarely have much value here, as they usually tend to be interesting to an audience of exactly one. Granted, there can be exceptions, if an answer illuminates a topic that the OP had misunderstood in a way that many can read & gain from.

But the more common case, I think, are questions like [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/95422/7532), which was closed (quite correctly, IMHO). Short of examining the OP's code (in MatLab or otherwise) line by line, there wasn't much to be done to find why the answer being gotten was unreasonable. And if the answer is "in line 22, use the SI constant of 123.456, instead of the English units constant of 654.321", how many people can benefit from that?

I'd differentiate this situation from StackOverflow's programming stacks, where the code tends to be of manageable size , and the corrected result tends to be useful to others attempting the same task, not just those encountering the same error. Particularly since SO strongly encouraged code in posts to be a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - which would be hard to do here, particularly for questions like the one linked above.