# An appeal to *just* vote to close

Tags: discussion, answers

Motivated by [An appeal regarding "Do-my-homework-for-me" questions](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4306/14897), even though I do **not** think this will be well-received, I'll say it anyway:

I do not like homework questions as much as anyone. My issue is with the unintentional subtle put-downs, which are against the Code of Conduct. And emphasis on *unintentional* and *subtle.*

For years it's common for answers to be posted that would take advantages of an unclear word or phrase, in an attempt to **outwit** the asker, while clearly not answering what is an unclear question to begin with. Sorry I won't post examples, but I'll just say that not everyone speaks English proficiently or knows the technical subtleties, so outwitting them while knowing full-well the question is unclear, is not nice.

I'd rather see unclear questions closed more quickly, than see established users having fun at their expense. Chat is always there for messing about, but unintentional subtle put-down answers are still put-downs.

All I'm saying here is: VTC and wait for OP, and optionally request clarification, and that should be the end of it.